# Kivy opens two popup windows, when I only expected one

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

So, I've been trying to get a popup to open on Kivy, and close it with when pressing Escape. However I found myself having to press it twice, and then I found out that it was opening two popups.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button

from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('kivy', 'exit_on_escape', '0')

class KeyDown(App):
    def build(self):
        self.popup_exists = 0
        Window.bind(on_key_down=self.key_action)
        return Widget()

    def key_action(self, *args):
        key1 = args[1]
        key2 = args[2]
        special_keys = args[4]
        letter = args[3]

        if special_keys == ['ctrl'] and letter == 'f':                          # Ctrl-F
            print('Find')
            self.open_find_dialog()
        if key1 == 13 and key2 == 40 and self.popup_exists == 1:                # ENTER KEY
            pass
        if key1 == 27 and key2 == 41 and self.popup_exists == 1:    # ESC
            self.find_window.dismiss()

    def open_find_dialog(self):
        content = BoxLayout(orientation='horizontal')
        col1_cont = BoxLayout(size_hint_x = 2,orientation = 'vertical')
        col2_cont = BoxLayout(size_hint_x = 4,orientation = 'vertical')
        find_labl = Label(text='Find',size_hint_y=None, height = 40)
        repl_labl = Label(text='Replace',size_hint_y=None, height = 40)

        find_text = TextInput(text='', size_hint_y = None, height = 40)
        repl_text = TextInput(text='', size_hint_y = None, height = 40)
        col1_cont.add_widget(find_labl)
        col1_cont.add_widget(repl_labl)
        col2_cont.add_widget(find_text)
        col2_cont.add_widget(repl_text)

        content.add_widget(col1_cont)
        content.add_widget(col2_cont)
        self.find_window = Popup(title='Find and Replace',content = content,size_hint=(None, None), size=(240, 140))
        self.find_window.open()
        self.popup_exists = 1
if __name__ == '__main__':
    KeyDown().run()
```

Does anyone know why would it open two popups? How would I prevent it from doing so?

Comment: I understand that you press twice Ctrl+f, why do you do it ?, if the popup is open and press Ctrl+f Should another popup open or just do nothing?

Comment: Appears to work correctly for me under kivy v1.11.0.dev0 and Python v3.6.6 under Ubuntu 18.04. What are your versions?

Comment: So, when I press Ctrl+F once, it opens two popups instead of one. Every time that I do any key combination, it runs that action twice instead of once. I have kivy v1.11.0.dev0, and Python 3.6.2 in Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: When looking more closely, every time I press a key by itself, I get as the events: 
`<kivy.core.window.window_sdl2.WindowSDL object at 0x7fc177103868>, 115, 22, 's', []`

Comment: But, when I press it with the Ctrl key, I get  

`<kivy.core.window.window_sdl2.WindowSDL object at 0x7fc177103868>, 305, 224, 'ı', ['ctrl']]`
`<kivy.core.window.window_sdl2.WindowSDL object at 0x7fc177103868>, 115, 22, 's', ['ctrl']`
`<kivy.core.window.window_sdl2.WindowSDL object at 0x7fc177103868>, 115, 22, 's', ['ctrl']`